# layer-4 firewall functionalities

Tags: networking, ip, protocols, firewall

Why a layer-4 firewall (a device that can look at all protocol headers up to the transport layer) cannot block all ICMP traffic?

ICMP is a IP layer protocol.Why can't we block all ICMP traffic using layer-4 firewall.Can it not be done by blocking IP adresses and port number?

Answer (score 2):

For blocking it , block the ip protocol `01` which number is for ICMP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers

Port number is a 4-layer conception, ICMP is at 3-layer.